# Failing to configure spring beans in grails 4.0.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, grails

I have a project tat I haven't touched for a while now, and we decided to recurrent it. This project is and API written in Grails 4.

The last time (several months ago) it was working and building fine. Right now if I run pretty much any grails command I am getting the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-09 22:34:20.225 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    okio.Segment.writeTo(Segment.kt:169)

The following method did not exist:

    kotlin.collections.ArraysKt.copyInto([B[BIII)[B

The method's class, kotlin.collections.ArraysKt, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/shurikag/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.71/d9717625bb3c731561251f8dd2c67a1011d6764c/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar!/kotlin/collections/ArraysKt.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/shurikag/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.71/d9717625bb3c731561251f8dd2c67a1011d6764c/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of kotlin.collections.ArraysKt


> Task :dbmUpdate FAILED
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
<-------------> 0% WAITING
> IDLE
Context failed to load: Error creating bean with name 'restTokenValidationFilter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'restAuthenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restAuthenticationProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStorageService' while setting bean property 'tokenStorageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStorageService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'auth0APIService' while setting bean property 'auth0APIService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auth0APIService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authApi' while setting bean property 'authAPI'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authApi': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.auth0.client.auth.AuthAPI]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.collections.ArraysKt.copyInto([B[BIII)[B

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dbmUpdate'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I assumption was that it has something to do with dependencies versions. Checked everything - even copied from another project that works... Does not help.

This is my `resources.groovy`:

```
import com.auth0.client.auth.AuthAPI
import edvengo.auth0.Auth0APIService
import edvengo.auth0.Auth0TokenStorageService
import edvengo.auth0.Auth0TokenVerificationService
import edvengo.auth0.Auth0UserResolverService
import edvengo.security.UserPasswordEncoderListener
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationProvider

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {

    userPasswordEncoderListener(UserPasswordEncoderListener)

    authApi(AuthAPI) { beanDefinition ->
        beanDefinition.constructorArgs = [
                '${edvengo.auth0.api.domain}',
                '${edvengo.auth0.api.clientId}',
                '${edvengo.auth0.api.clientSecret}'
        ]
    }

    auth0APIService(Auth0APIService) {
        authAPI = ref('authApi')
    }

    auth0TokenVerificationService(Auth0TokenVerificationService)

    auth0UserResolverService(Auth0UserResolverService)

    tokenStorageService(Auth0TokenStorageService) {
        jwtService = ref('jwtService')
        userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
        auth0TokenVerificationService = ref('auth0TokenVerificationService')
        auth0APIService = ref('auth0APIService')
        auth0UserResolverService = ref('auth0UserResolverService')
    }

    /* restAuthenticationProvider */
    restAuthenticationProvider(RestAuthenticationProvider) {
        tokenStorageService = ref('tokenStorageService')
        useJwt = false
        jwtService = ref('jwtService')
    }

}
```

At this point, my assumption is that the problem only with `authApi` bean. Possibly with constructor arguments. Checked that the environment variables are defined properly.

What else can be a reason?

Just as a reference. my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.0.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4"
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.1.0.RC1'
    }
}

version "0.2"
group "edvengo.api"

// apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"

repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.12.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:3.0.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.18.Final"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:views-json-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.20.Final"

    compile "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:postgresql-extensions:7.0.0"
    compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.20"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.1.0.RC1'
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.1'

    compile "com.auth0:auth0:1.31.0"
    compile "com.auth0:jwks-rsa:0.18.0"

    compile 'com.papertrailapp:logback-syslog4j:1.0.0'
    compile "com.stripe:stripe-java:20.56.0"

    compile "com.sendinblue:sib-api-v3-sdk:5.2.0"

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:async:4.0.0"
    compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-async"

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72'

}

bootRun {
    ignoreExitValue true
    jvmArgs(
            '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
            '-noverify',
            '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
            '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    configure(groovyOptions) {
        forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1024m']
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code around line 169 of `Segment.kt`?

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue (`NoSuchMethodError kotlin.collections.ArraysKt.copyInto`) after adding okhttp dependency to my Grails 4.0.10 project. I found [here](https://medium.com/agorapulse-stories/how-to-use-okhttp-4-x-with-grails-f6387fe4460e) an explanation:

> The issue is caused by the old version of the Kotlin libraries on the
> classpath. Grails 4.x framework is still using Spring Dependency
> Management Plugin under the hood with a couple of Maven BOMs secretly
> added under the hood. One of them is an older version of Spring Boot
> Dependencies BOM which specifies the version of Kotlin libraries to
> 1.2.71 whereas OkHttp depends on 1.4.10 at the time of writing causing the binary incompatibility in the runtime.

and the solution:

> Luckily, there is an easy solution to fix this. The Kotlin version is
> specified as kotlin.version property in the BOM and Spring Dependency
> Management Plugin supports overriding the properties in
> `gradle.properties` file so the only required change is to add the
> following line at the end of the file.

```
kotlin.version = 1.4.10
```